# XcodeにおけるFTGLのリンクについて

Tags: xcode, macos, opengl, font

macOS，Xcode上で，freetype2とFTGLを使って文字をグラフィクス上で描写したいのですが，エラーが出てうまくいきません．エラーは以下のように出ます．

```
Undefined symbol: FTPixmapFont::FTPixmapFont(char const*)
Undefined symbol: FTPixmapFont::~FTPixmapFont()
Undefined symbol: FTFont::Render(char const*, int, FTPoint, FTPoint, int)
Undefined symbol: FTFont::FaceSize(unsigned int, unsigned int)
Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

C++main file のコードは以下の通りです．

```
#include <iostream>
#include <GLUT/GLUT.h>
#include <ft2build.h>
#include <ftgl.h>
#include <FTGL/FTGLPixmapFont.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    // insert code here...
    std::cout << "Hello, World!\n";
 
    FTGLPixmapFont font("Arial.ttf");
    font.FaceSize(72);
    font.Render("Hello World!");
    
    return 0;
}
```

• header search pathsには
/usr/local/include/freetype-2.13.2/include/
/usr/local/include/ftgl-2.1.3~rc5/src/

• library search pathsには
/usr/local/lib

• Other Linker Flags
のところには何も記述していません．

`-lftgl` を入れると，
Library not found for -lftgl
というエラーメッセージが出ます．

• Link binary with librariesには
OpenGL.framework，AGL.framework，GLUT.frameworkが入っています．

最終的にはopen dynamics engineという物理シミュレータをxcode上で使い，出力した速度情報などをグラフィクス上にロボットと一緒に表示させることを目的としています．

library search path のところに追加で記述しないといけないのでしょうか．
何かご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたら，教えていただけないでしょうか．どうぞよろしくお願いいたします．

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: FTGL は [こちら](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ftgl/) から入手したものでしょうか？ヘッダファイルは含まれているものの、ライブラリは別途コンパイルが必要なようにも見えます。

Comment: お恥ずかしい話ですが，色々とやりすぎて，もはや覚えていません．
こちらか，
https://sourceforge.net/projects/ftgl/
もしくはhomebrew経由だったかと思います．
https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/ftgl

Answer (score 0):

プロジェクトの`Build Phase`内の`Link Binary With Libraries`に`libFTGL.??`を追加する必要があります

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

の+をクリックして、
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

`Add Other`ボタンで、ライブラリーパスから、`libfgtl.a`または`libfgtl.dylib`を選択、追加して下さい。
また、ftglに限らず、Xcodeで作成中のアプリに必用なライブラリーは、全てここに追加してリンクすることを明示する必要があります。

Comment: libftgl.aまたはlibftgl.dylibを入れてみたり，両方，関係ありそうなものをLink Binary with Libraryに入れてみたのですが，エラーは消えませんでした．

Comment: targetがany architectureになってますが、ソースのコンパイルはUniversal Binaryで、ライブラリーはx86_64またはarmのどちらかのみのアーキテクチャになっていたりしませんか？

Comment: 「targetがany architecture」というのは分かるのですが，「ソースのコンパイルはUniversal Binaryで、ライブラリーはx86_64またはarmのどちらかのみのアーキテクチャ」というのはどこで確認すれば良いのか分かりませんでした．申し訳ありません．
productsの中のtargets名が赤くなっていることと何か関係があるのでしょうか？

Comment: Target→Build settings→Architecturs→ArchtecturesがStandard architecutreになっていれば、ユニバーサルバイナリーでのビルドを行っていることになります。ライブラリーがどのアーキテクチャーのライブラリーかは、`lipo -archs libftgl.a`で見られると思います

Comment: Target→Build settings→Architecturs→ArchtecturesがStandard architecutreになっていました．

ターミナルには　lipo -archs libftgl.a
を打ち込んだのですが，
fatal error: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/lipo: can't open input file: libftgl.a (No such file or directory)
と出てしまい，見ることができませんでした．
lipo -info libftgl.a　でも
fatal error: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/lipo: can't open input file: libftgl.a (No such file or directory)
でした．

Comment: `lipo`は、バイナリーが置いてあるディレクトリーで実行しないと動きませんので、/usr/local/lib 下か、libftgl.aがあるディレクトリーに移動して実行してください

Comment: ありがとうございます．libftgl.a，libftgl.dylib，libftgl.2.dylib，どれもx86_64でした．

Comment: なら、architectureをStandardから、x86_64に書き替えると動くかも知れません

Comment: PROJECTS→Build Setting→Architecturesの，
Standard Architectures (Apple Silcon,Intel) = $(ARCHS_STANDARD)の
$(ARCHS_STANDARD)を消して
ARCHS_STANDARD =  x86_64
と入力してみたのですが，やはり同じエラーが出てしまいました．また，
TARGETS→Build Setting→Architecturesも
$(ARCHS_STANDARD)を消して
ARCHS_STANDARD =  x86_64
と入力してみたのですが，No eligible devices connected 'My mac’となりビルドができなくなります．
Excluded architecture→DebugとReleaseにarm64と入れると「No eligible devices connected 'My mac’」となり，ビルドができませんでした．